# How can I redirect one URL with a query string to another and carry it over?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

No matter how hard I search for help with htaccess redirect/rewrite rules, I never seem to find an exact match for my problem. And with htaccess, you can't exactly wing it on the syntax!

Please help me redirect any traffic to:

**/blue-widgets?param=value1**

Needs to redirect straight to:

**/blue-widgets/compare-widgets?param=value1**

It's probably obvious but the redirect should not happen to any traffic to:

**/blue-widgets (direct)**
OR
**/blue-widgets?param={any other value}**

Thank you and Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)param=value1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blue-widgets)/?$ /$1/compare-widgets [L,NC,R=302]
```

Query string is by default carried over to target URL.

Comment: Thank you, but getting absolutely no redirection whatsoever. Am I able email you a link to the domain/page and show me you my htaccess please?

Comment: Make sure this is your first rule below `RewriteEngine` line. You can also provide your htaccess using pastebin.com link

Comment: Moving above all my WordPress generated stuff worked! Thank you.